# how cache react prop to ref?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My component hava a onChange prop,
I don't want onChange fire useEffect,
so I want cache onChange to a ref,
below is my code,i don't know the code is right or not.

```js
const Component = ({onChange})=>{
    const onChangeRef = useRef(onChange);
    onChangeRef.current = onChange;
    
    const [state, setState] = useState();

    useEffect(()=>{
        onChangeRef.current();
    },[state]);

    //....some code
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want onChange fire useEffect

You can't do that in *quite* the way you've shown because by the time your function component is called, it's *already* in the process of rendering. It has to be memo-ized to prevent that using a "[Higher Order Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)." You could do *just* the memo-izing via `React.memo` with a custom `areEqual` callback, but your component would use a stale copy of the `onChange` prop. Instead, let's write our own siple HOC that provides a stable `onChange` in place of an unstable `onChange`.

```
function withStableOnChange(WrappedComponent) {
    let latestProps;

    // Our stable onChange function -- not an arrow function so that
    // it can pass on the `this` it's called with
    const onChange = function(...args) {
        return latestProps.onChange.apply(this, args);
    };

    // use `React.memo` to memo-ize the component:
    return React.memo(
        (props) => {
            latestProps = props; // Need this for the first render to work
            return <WrappedComponent {...props} onChange={onChange} />;
        },
        (prevProps, nextProps) => {
            // Remember the latest props, since we may not render
            latestProps = nextProps;

            // Props "are equal" if all of them are the same other than `onChange`
            const allPropNames = new Set([
                ...Object.keys(prevProps),
                ...Object.keys(nextProps),
            ]);
            for (const name of allPropNames) {
                if (name !== "onChange" && prevProps[name] !== nextProps[name]) {
                    return false; // Not equal
                }
            }
            return true; // Props are "equal"
        }
    );
}
```

Here's a live example. Notice that when you click the `+` in the first one ('Using component "without wrapper"'), the child component gets re-rendered because the parent component's `onChange` is unstable. But when you click the `+` in the second one ('Using component "with wrapper"'), the child-component doesn't get re-rendered because `withStableOnChange` memo-izes it and provides it with a stable version of `onChange` instead of the unstable one it receives.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function withStableOnChange(WrappedComponent) {
    let latestProps;

    // Our stable onChange function -- not an arrow function so that
    // it can pass on the `this` it's called with
    const onChange = function(...args) {
        return latestProps.onChange.apply(this, args);
    };

    // use `React.memo` to memo-ize the component:
    return React.memo(
        (props) => {
            latestProps = props; // Need this for the first render to work
            return <WrappedComponent {...props} onChange={onChange} />;
        },
        (prevProps, nextProps) => {
            // Remember the latest props, since we may not render
            latestProps = nextProps;

            // Props "are equal" if all of them are the same other than `onChange`
            const allPropNames = new Set([
                ...Object.keys(prevProps),
                ...Object.keys(nextProps),
            ]);
            for (const name of allPropNames) {
                if (name !== "onChange" && prevProps[name] !== nextProps[name]) {
                    return false; // Not equal
                }
            }
            return true; // Props are "equal"
        }
    );
}

const ComponentWithoutWrapper = ({onChange, componentType}) => {
    const [state, setState] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        onChange(state);
    }, [state]);

    console.log(`Re-rendering the component "${componentType}"`);
    return (
        <input type="text" value={state} onChange={({currentTarget: {value}}) => setState(value)} />
    );
};

const ComponentWithWrapper = withStableOnChange(ComponentWithoutWrapper);

const Test = ({componentType, ChildComponent}) => {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

    // This `onChange` changes on every render of `Example`
    const onChange = (value) => {
        // Using `counter` here to prove the up-to-date version of this function gets
        // when `ComponentWithWrapper` is used.
        console.log(`Got change event: ${value}, counter = ${counter}`);
    };

    return <div>
        <div>Using component "{componentType}":</div>
        <ChildComponent onChange={onChange} componentType={componentType} />
        <div>
            Example counter: {counter}{" "}
            <input type="button" onClick={() => setCounter(c => c + 1)} value="+" />
        </div>
    </div>;
};

const App = () => {
    // (Sadly, Stack Snippets don't support <>...</>)
    return <React.Fragment>
        <Test componentType="without wrapper" ChildComponent={ComponentWithoutWrapper} />
        <Test componentType="with wrapper"    ChildComponent={ComponentWithWrapper} />
    </React.Fragment>;
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

`withStableOnChange` is just an example. In a real HOC, you'd probably at least make the name of the prop a parameter, and maybe even make it possible to handle multiple function props rather than just one.

---

Just for completeness, here's a copy of `withStableOnChange` that uses a `class` component rather than `React.memo`. Both versions support using either `class` components or function components as the component they wrap, it's purely a matter of whether you write the HOC using a function component or a `class` component.

```
function withStableOnChange(WrappedComponent) {
    return class extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            const instance = this;
            // Our stable onChange function -- not an arrow function so that
            // it can pass on the `this` it's called with
            this.onChange = function(...args) {
                return instance.props.onChange.apply(this, args);
            };
        }
        shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
            // Component should update if any prop other than `onChange` changed
            const allPropNames = new Set([
                ...Object.keys(this.props),
                ...Object.keys(nextProps),
            ]);
            for (const name of allPropNames) {
                if (name !== "onChange" && this.props[name] !== nextProps[name]) {
                    return true; // Component should update
                }
            }
            return false; // No need for component to update
        }
        render() {
            return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} onChange={this.onChange} />;
        }
    };
}
```

That live example using this version of `withStableOnChange` instead:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function withStableOnChange(WrappedComponent) {
    return class extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            const instance = this;
            // Our stable onChange function -- not an arrow function so that
            // it can pass on the `this` it's called with
            this.onChange = function(...args) {
                return instance.props.onChange.apply(this, args);
            };
        }
        shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
            // Component should update if any prop other than `onChange` changed
            const allPropNames = new Set([
                ...Object.keys(this.props),
                ...Object.keys(nextProps),
            ]);
            for (const name of allPropNames) {
                if (name !== "onChange" && this.props[name] !== nextProps[name]) {
                    return true; // Component should update
                }
            }
            return false; // No need for component to update
        }
        render() {
            return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} onChange={this.onChange} />;
        }
    };
}

const ComponentWithoutWrapper = ({onChange, componentType}) => {
    const [state, setState] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        onChange(state);
    }, [state]);

    console.log(`Re-rendering the component "${componentType}"`);
    return (
        <input type="text" value={state} onChange={({currentTarget: {value}}) => setState(value)} />
    );
};

const ComponentWithWrapper = withStableOnChange(ComponentWithoutWrapper);

const Test = ({componentType, ChildComponent}) => {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

    // This `onChange` changes on every render of `Example`
    const onChange = (value) => {
        // Using `counter` here to prove the up-to-date version of this function gets
        // when `ComponentWithWrapper` is used.
        console.log(`Got change event: ${value}, counter = ${counter}`);
    };

    return <div>
        <div>Using component "{componentType}":</div>
        <ChildComponent onChange={onChange} componentType={componentType} />
        <div>
            Example counter: {counter}{" "}
            <input type="button" onClick={() => setCounter(c => c + 1)} value="+" />
        </div>
    </div>;
};

const App = () => {
    // (Sadly, Stack Snippets don't support <>...</>)
    return <React.Fragment>
        <Test componentType="without wrapper" ChildComponent={ComponentWithoutWrapper} />
        <Test componentType="with wrapper"    ChildComponent={ComponentWithWrapper} />
    </React.Fragment>;
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```